# Clean URL redirection htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a website SongsBar.com , when a query is searched on my website, the url in the browser displays like this - http://songsbar.com/download.php?q={search text}.
i want it be appear like this http://songsbar.com/download/{search text}.html

Comment: i want this format - http://songsbar.com/download/{search text}.html to appear right in the address bar of the search result page.

Comment: for example when a querry is searched on mp3skull.com the url of the search result page appears like this - http://mp3skull/mp3/{search text}.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to make sure Multiviews (mod_negotiation) is turned off, otherwise it'll mess with the `/download/` and `/download.php` stuff.

Then you need to externally redirect requests for `download.php`

Then you need to internally rewrite the `/download/` requests *back* to the php file (the browser is oblivious to this happening.

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+download.php\?q=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /download/%1.html? [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteRule ^download/(.+)\.html$ /download.php?q=$1 [L,B,QSA]
```

The `B` flag *may* not be necessary. It depends on what kind of stuff you plan on putting in the parameter. The flag ensures that special characters get encoded.

Comment: sir , is r=301 is important ?

Comment: @raps786 The `R` tells mod_rewrite to externally redirect the browser, the `=301` part makes it a permanent redirect.

Comment: this is giving http://songsbar.com/download/{search text}.html which i wanted, but with 404 error :( i just copied this all and pasted there

Comment: @raps786 forgot to match against the `\.html`

Comment: match against the \.html ?

Comment: sir waiting with ur match :) hope it will give me what i want ... aameen

Comment: @raps786 Not sure what's wrong, [it works perfectly fine for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8hxTN.png).

Comment: grt sir its working ... just one last query thn will not disturb u

Comment: little error.. sir its exmple if i search for "whats your name" its taking as "whats+your+name" !! how to avoid this i mean its not showing results for "whats your name" but showing for "whats+your+name"

Comment: earlier i was using this 

RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^download/(.*).html download.php?q=$1&p=1 [L,QSA]

Comment: and how to adjust &p=1 ?

Comment: @raps added the `NE` and `QSA` flags

Comment: all done sir very very thank u !!

sir how to adjust &p=1 ( p=1 : page 1 ) and can we replace "+" with "_" ?

if u can , thn visit www.SongsBar.com and see have a self experience ...

Comment: :) i tried myself and made it ( &p=1) now only left is to replace PLUS with UNDER SCORE !!

Comment: can we replace "+" with "_" between the searched terms ??? eg. ...download/a+b+c.html to ...download/a_b_c.html !!!

Answer (score 1):

.htaccess

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^download/([^/]*)\.html$ /download.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Something like : RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^download/(.*).html download.php?q=$1&p=1 [L,QSA]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with something along the lines of:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /download/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  #if the file actually exists don't rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /download.php?q=$1 [L]
```